# Linear transformation of random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

We have to stochastic variables X and Y, and we define

$ \begin{pmatrix} \tilde{X} \\ \tilde{Y} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} X \\ Y \end{pmatrix} $

for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\tilde{X}=aX+bY$ and $\tilde{Y}=cX+dY$. We know that both $X$ and Y, and $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ are uncorrelated, and the distribution of (X,Y) has density $g(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$. Here $f$ is a density with respect to the lebesgue measure for a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and f is continous and strict positive.

Furthermore, we say that the distribution of (X,Y) is invariant to orthogonal matrices $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} $ if $(X,Y)$ and $(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$, have equal distributions. In general, a matrix O is orthogonal if $OO^T=O^TO=I$, where I is the identity matrix.

Now I have to show that if the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is invariant to orthogonal transformations, then it holds that

$f(x)f(y)=f(0)f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ 
for alle $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [joint density invariant under orthogonal transformations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068123/joint-density-invariant-under-orthogonal-transformations)

Answer (score 1):

Consider orthogonal matrix

$$ A = \left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
      \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}& \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}  \\
      -\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} & \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} 
    \end{array}
  \right).
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you maybe give me a hint of how to use this matrix, because i can't see how? @Khashaa