# Joint density invariant under orthogonal transformations

Tags: probability-theory

I have a problem and I am totally stuck!

I have to show that when the distribution of two random variables $X$ & $Y$ given by $g(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$ is invariant to orthogonal transformations, then it holds that $$f(x)f(y)=f(0)f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right).$$

Any ideas on how to approach this? I have found that when the random variables are transformed by an orthogonal matrix like this $\scriptstyle \begin{bmatrix}\tilde{X}\\\tilde{Y}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\times \begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\end{bmatrix}$, then the distribution of $(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$ is given by $\tilde{g}(x,y)=f\left(\frac{dx-by}{ad-bc}\right)f\left(\frac{ay-cx}{ad-bc}\right)$, and my thought was that maybe it could be proven that $f\left(\frac{dx-by}{ad-bc}\right)f\left(\frac{ay-cx}{ad-bc}\right)=f(0)f\left(\sqrt{\scriptstyle\left(\frac{dx-by}{ad-bc}\right)^2+\left(\frac{ay-cx}{ad-bc}\right)^2}\right)$, but it doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: @StefanHansen: It sure is, but on the whole, I'd (slightly) prefer to close that one as a dupe of this, since this one is more coherently written and has (IMO) a better answer.

Comment: (I also wonder which homework set / exam / whatever this question is from; surely two identical questions within two days can't be a coincidence...)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: there is an orthogonal transformation (rotation) that takes $(x,y)$ to $(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, 0)$.

Comment: Thank you ;) So I found this transformation, but how is this a complete answer to the problem? I would think that I have only proven the equality for this particular orthogonal transformation, but not for an arbitrary one?

Much appreciated :)

Comment: The equality is an equality, not just "an equality for this particular orthogonal transformation".

Comment: I see, thank you very much!